Problem to get records using hasMany and orWhere in Laravel
I have hasMany relation in User model:
public function wins() {
    return $this->hasMany(Win::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

I want to get records from winners table, "where user_id = 5865535 AND (app_id = 730 OR state = 'new')"
$user = \App\User::find(5865535);
$wins = $user->wins()->where('app_id', 730)->orWhere('state', 'new')->pluck('user_id')->unique();

But I got records with different user_id
0 => 4909807
18 => 4909808
143 => 4909867
144 => 4909868
145 => 4909870
148 => 4909871
271 => 4916186
312 => 5865535

I have fix like this:
$wins = $user->wins()->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('app_id', 730)->orWhere('state', 'new');
})->first();

Output:
 0 => 5865535

But I want to know why my first variant is not working? Maybe this is a bug?
Laravel version: 9.52.16
PHP version: 8.1.13

Not a bug. If you change ->pluck('user_id')->unique() to ->toSql(), you'll probably see your query as WHERE user_id = ... AND app_id = ... OR state = ... (without the () around your 2nd clause). The way you have it with ->where(function () { ... }) is correct to create the () around your AND ... OR ... condition.

When you use orWhere('status' , new) in this case it will check in wins where is 'new' and it will ignore all the other conditions like app_id == 730 and user_id ==  5865535.
This is what I think, to solve this you may not use orWhere in this case
